# Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell XPS is draining power very fast

Tags: 18.04, dell, power-management, laptop, battery

I installed ubuntu version 18.04 on my dell xps laptop and the battery drain is just too fast.

The lap top is only a few months old and I am mostly running browser based applications.  After a full charge , the battery only last slightly longer than one hour.

I am not running any excessive background processes and have lowered my screen brightness.

Are there steps I can take to optimize my batter life?

Thanks 
-U

Comment: trying to bump this.  Can someone please point me at least to some direction?  I am surprised I am getting no replies at all

Comment: trying to bump this thread again